# How to add multiple numbers in one list (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, numbers

Say if I want to add 11 to all the numbers in the variable "e". How would I do it?

```
ans = input("Enter here string of numbers here") 
add = input("How much do you want to add each individual numbers by: ")  #here is when it will minus each individual number print(output)
```

`e = "21,45,42,71"`

So it should now say (after you add 11 and print it)

`32,56,53,82`

code:

````
ans = input("Enter string of numbers here")
add = input("How much do you want to add each individual numbers by: ")

#here is when it will minus each individual number
print(output)```
````

Comment: We love that you're here with us and we need to see your code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Is there a reason you use a string to store the numbers? Why not directly a list?

Comment: im not using a list because it is meant to take an input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
a= "21,45,42,71" #your string
lst = list(map(int,a.split(","))) #splitted every number and converted to int and stored in list
result = list(map(lambda x:x+11,lst)) #added 11 to each number
print(result)
```

Comment: Yes it works, thanks!

Comment: I was about to but it said ii had to wait, dont worry tho because i accepted it

Answer (score 1):

First, you split the terms, then convert them into an integer, add them, then convert them back to string, and print them.

```
ans = input("Enter here string of numbers here: ").split(",") 
add = input("How much do you want to add each individual numbers by: ")
print("Here is the sum: ",','.join([str(int(answer)+int(add)) for answer in ans]))
```

This is the main part of the code:

```
','.join([str(int(answer)+int(add)) for answer in ans])
```

a `join` operator needs a a list of **string** with another string to join them.

Here, `[str(int(answer)+int(add)) for answer in ans]` means convert the `answer` and `add` to an integer, add them, and convert them back to a string. Then, the `.join()` joins the list with the string provided. Since `,` is provided, the output will be `32,56,53,82`

Comment: Slight nitpick: You don't need a list comprehension. `str.join()` takes a generator expression and evaluates each element, so you can save one traversal of the list

Answer (score 0):

If you need the result as a single string:

```
output = ",".join(str(int(add) + int(x)) for x in ans.split(","))
print(output)
```

If you're ok with the result being a list of numbers:

```
putput = [int(add) + int(x) for x in ans.split(",")]
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for string input => string output:

```
e = "21,45,42,71"

','.join([str(int(x)+11) for x in e.split(',')])
# Out[29]: '32,56,53,82'
```

---

Input list of integers => list of integers:

```
e = [21, 45, 42, 71]

[x+11 for x in e]
# Out[33]: [32, 56, 53, 82]
```

---

Input list of integers => list of integers (with library)

```
e = [21, 45, 42, 71]

import numpy as np
np.add(e, 11).tolist()
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Answer (score 0):

try some list comprehension

```
ans = input("Enter here string of numbers here: ") 
add = input("How much do you want to add each individual numbers by: ")

nums = [int(x)+int(add) for x in ans.split(',')]
print(nums)
```

out

```
Enter here string of numbers here:  23,24,25,26
How much do you want to add each individual numbers by:  11
[34, 35, 36, 37]
```

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Ha